# Get the NavController after creating a NavHostFragment programmatically

Tags: android, navigation

I create a `NavHostFragment` programmatically in the method `onCreate` method of my `Activity` just like this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#create_a_navhostfragment) says, but then the method `findNavController(R.id.nav_host)` throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.klosed.ui/app.klosed.ui.host.HostActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity app.klosed.ui.host.HostActivity@d3f794e does not have a NavController set on 2131231026
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity app.klosed.ui.host.HostActivity@d3f794e does not have a NavController set on 2131231026
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:61)
        at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
        at app.klosed.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:78)
        at app.klosed.ui.host.HostActivity.onCreate(HostActivity.kt:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
```

How can I get the `NavController` object?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavController navController = ((NavHostFragment) Objects.requireNonNull(fragment)).getNavController();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id. nav_host)
```

Comment: This throws the same exception becasue `findNavController(R.id.nav_host)` is only a Kotlin extension function that wraps `Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host)`.